Difference between cell complexes and simplicial complexes
A cell is a convex hull of its vertices .
A cell complex in $R^n$ is a finite set of cells in $R^n$ , $K$ such that...
(i)If $A \in K$ then every face of $A$ is in $K$
(ii)If $A$ and $B$ in $K$ , then $A \cap B = \phi$ or $A \cap B = $ common face of $A$ and $B$.
An n-simplex in $R^n$ is the convex hull of (n+1)-linearly independent points , called its vertices .
A simplicial complex is a cell complexes whose cells are all simplices.
I am currently studying PL Topology . I am confused about the difference between cell complexes and simplicial complexes .Can you please help me by giving a picture or example that is cell complexes but not simplicial complexes ?

This is not how cells are defined in topology. What book are you reading?

@MoisheKohan Piecewise Linear Topology by J.F.P. Hudson .

The underlying space of a cell complex, i.e. the union of its cells, is a compact polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Conversely, every compact polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$ admits a triangulation, i.e. there is a simplicial complex whose underlying space is that compact polyhedron. Thus, at the level of underlying spaces, there is no difference between cell complexes and simplicial complexes. The actual difference lies in the additional data of how the space is decomposed into cells and simplices respectively, where cell complexes allow more flexibility.
It is clear that every simplex is a cell, but the converse is far from true. E.g. any convex quadrilateral in a plane is a convex hull of $4$ points, but this is not a simplex. Now, any cell resp. simplex yields a cell resp. simplicial complex consisting of that cell resp. simplex together with all its faces, so cells that are not simplices yield examples of cell complexes that are not simplicial complexes. If you take a convex quadrilateral as before, this yields a cell complex with $4$ $0$-cells, $4$ $1$-cells and $1$ $2$-cell. You can 'subdivide' this cell complex to obtain a simplicial complex with the same underlying space, having $4$ $0$-simplices, $5$ $1$-simplices and $2$ $2$-simplices. I suggest you draw the corresponding pictures to get a feel.

@mathlearner: I noticed that you have not accepted any answers to your questions.  Take a look at our guidelines for What should I do when someone answers my question?.
